# Markdown algorithm: sequence of # followed by enter should return nothing

Tags: java, markdown

So now I have this method:

```
public static String convert(String str) {

    if (str.equals("# "))
    System.out.println(" ");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(#+[^#]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String str1 = matcher.group(1);
    int n = str1.length() - str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length();
System.out.println("<h" + n + ">" + str1.substring(n) + "</h" + n + ">");
}

return ("");
}
```

When I type ###Le Monde # it gives me < h3>Le Monde < /h3> < h1> < /h1>. I would like it to ignore the # following "le monde". Basically, I want the algorithm to ignore a series of # followed by a space or return key. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect it to behave any differently? Unless the entire string is "# ", each run of hashes will be replaced by markup in the while loop.

Comment: After I have read all your Markdown question: I think it would be easier you use a framework like f.ex. [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki). The source of [Pegdown](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown) (which uses Parboiled to parse Markdown text) is easy to read and extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another line after getting the next match (str1), so:

```
String str1 = matcher.group(1);
if(str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").length() == 0 || str1.replaceFirst("#+", "").matches("[\\s]+")) continue;
```

That will ignore any whitespaces matches.

Comment: fixed it so now it checks after matching